# How to include multiple Commits into a PullRequest in VSO-Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, pull-request

For instance I made a code commit for BuxFix10 and published into vso-Git .Then after some time ,I found some issue with my code fix and made more changes and published another code commit(for BuxFix10) into vso git .Now I want to create a Pull-request that includes both my commits .So that I can send all my code changes related to the bug fix to be reviewed by my team. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want people on your team to review code in a Git team project on Visual Studio Online, you can use a pull request to review and merge the code. Pull requests enable developers working in topic branches to get feedback on their changes from other developers prior to submitting the code into the master branch. Any developer participating in the review can see the code changes, leave comments in the code, and give a "thumbs up" approval if they're satisfied with those changes. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/06/10/git-pull-request-visual-studio-online.aspx

So, in your scenario, when you want to others review your code, you need to branch the code, and change the code in branch, have commits. Then when you create a pull request, select "Review changes in branch relative to master", all commits in the branch will list here. You team will see the code changes between branch and master.